# Problem with connecting frontend and backend services through internal load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services

Frontend and backend service seem to be working fine separately on its own, but when I try to communicate between frontend and backend I keep getting ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error.

- Service discovery are all connected
- All security groups are open

[image: (edited) my AWS architecture]

I think our architecture is very similar to this if that helps.
(https://mohamedwaelbenismail.medium.com/microservices-architecture-deployed-on-ecs-fargate-based-cluster-using-cloudformation-878cb6f90571)

- It only works if we change the internal load balancer to public load balancer allow internet traffic and allow 0.0.0.0/0.
- Status of health check are all 'healthy'

Comment: You have to provide more information, on what exactly you do that you get `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. Also your architecture diagram does not really make any sense as Internal load balancer must be withing VPC (not outside of it) and it can't be "connected" to Internet gateway. I would suggest re-thinking your architecture and clarifying what exactly do you want to accomplish.

Comment: @Marcin Hi. Thanks for the feedback. I changed the wording in the image from internal load balancer to 'internet facing load balancer.' Sorry about the mix up. It must've been a typo. I get ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED when I try to send a http request to backend. I'm not sure, but I believe that maybe it has something to do with internal load balancer that routes traffic to the backend containers and that it's not working as it should.

Comment: What backend? Send request how? What is the source of the request? An ECS container? Your question lacks details and is unclear sadly.

Comment: @Marcin Sorry about the ambiguity of my question.  
So, 'IOL SERVER' is the backend (Fast API) and 'IOL FRONT' is my React web application. I made the request from my front end code by using axios. Also, front and back use separate ecs containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your schematic illustration, your `React web application` front end will never be able to reach your backend. Your front end executes on a client side in their browsers/mobiles. This means that the only way to reach backend is through **internet**. So your backend can't be in a private subnet behind an internal load balancer.

You have to re-architect your application. Both frontend and backund **must be** accessible from the internet, for your front end to be able to query the backend.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Another question if I may ask, is there no way to make our backend private? or not visible to end-users then? Would I have to change our framework from React to something else for that to work?

Comment: @SooJung No, there is no way if you access backend from the frontend directly. You can proxy the access through, e.g. API gateway, or second public ALB. But either way, backend must be accessible from the internet, with or without a proxy.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your insight. We'll try fixing our architecture and try deploying it again.